# Prefill Google Form field by clicking on a grid element (number)

Tags: javascript, html, google-forms

How can I accomplish this logic?
1- Click on a grid element on my site (https://puntogreen.netlify.app/) to pick a winning number.
2- Prefill that number in the google form field called "Numero a jugar" (number to play).

This is my JS, but is not prefilling the number.

```
// Update the form URL with the selected index
function openFormModal(index) {
  const formUrl = `https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSeQH_b3787iD5FreBxcgmmvdh_DTK75NqVUSktKi9zUYVHxOg/viewform?embedded=true&entryT2Ybvb16=${index}`;
  document.querySelector("#formModal iframe").src = formUrl;
// Show the form modal
  document.getElementById("formModal").style.display = "flex";

  // Add click event listener to the modal overlay
  document.querySelector(".modal").addEventListener("click", function () {
    closeFormModal();
  });
  // Set the value of the "Numero a jugar" field in the form
  const numeroAJugar = document.getElementById("T2Ybvb6");
  console.log("Setting value for Numero a jugar:", index);
  numeroAJugar.textContent = index;
}
```

Comment: You can not access elements inside a frame that had its content loaded from a different origin - the Same Origin Policy prevents that. This can only be accomplished, if Google was offering any JavaScript API to interact with these "embedded" forms from the outside (don't know if they do, you'd have to research that.)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to apply grid style to select options with pure CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69990951/is-it-possible-to-apply-grid-style-to-select-options-with-pure-css)